# Promtail End Point Failure At /loki/api/v1/push On EC2 Instance Via Docker

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, logging, grafana-loki, promtail

I am using aws Instance and I am trying to run promtail in order to fetch logs and forward it to loki server. Promtail, Loki and Grafana are being run through Docker.
The Loki Server is runing on port 3100, Promtail on 3400 and Loki on 8001. Since It is an AWS platform what needs to be done so that It stops throwing error at http://43.206.43.87:3100/loki/api/v1/push end point.

here is my promtail-config.yaml

```
server:
  http_listen_port: 3400
  grpc_listen_port: 0

positions:
  filename: /tmp/positions.yaml

clients:
  - url: http://43.206.43.87:3100/loki/api/v1/push

scrape_configs:
- job_name: system
  static_configs:
  - targets:
      - 43.206.43.87
    labels:
      job: varlogs
      __path__: /var/log/*log
```

Here is my loki-config.yaml

```
auth_enabled: false

server:
  http_listen_port: 3100
  grpc_listen_port: 0

common:
  path_prefix: /tmp/loki
  storage:
    filesystem:
      chunks_directory: /tmp/loki/chunks
      rules_directory: /tmp/loki/rules
  replication_factor: 1
  ring:
    instance_addr: 43.206.43.87
    kvstore:
      store: inmemory

schema_config:
  configs:
    - from: 2020-10-24
      store: boltdb-shipper
      object_store: filesystem
      schema: v11
      index:
        prefix: index_
        period: 24h

ruler:
  alertmanager_url: http://localhost:9093
```

Please help me out

Answer (score 0):

All I had to do was change the loki-config.yaml file in that
I had to write

```
instance_addr: localhost
```

and everything worked

Answer (score 0):

this problem is solved by changing the security group of ubuntu instance where the loki is runnning and allowing traffic from the ip 0.0.0.0/0 to the tcp port of 3100 that is where the loki server is running